# What happens when you await a Task before returning it?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I am experimenting with the new async and await keywords. I produced the following asynchronous function:

```
private async static Task<string> GetStringAsync(string pageAddress)
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    return client.GetStringAsync(pageAddress);
}
```

I understand that I am returning a `Task<String>` and can await the result from another method. This method works fine. My question is what happens (under the hood as it were) when I replace the second line of the above function with the following (notice the introduction of the *await* keyword):

```
return await client.GetStringAsync(pageAddress);
```

The function behaves in exactly the same way! Remember the function returns `Task<string>` not `string`. Is the `await` keyword here degenerate? Does the compiler simply strip it from my code?

Comment: check this link http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2012/06/26/understanding-a-simple-async-program.aspx

Comment: Are you sure the first version compiles?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Eric Lippert pointed out, the first version won't compile; you have to remove the `async` keyword or you'll get a type error.

Here's a useful mental model regarding how the `async` and `await` keywords work with the return type:

- Any value `T` returned by an `async` method is "wrapped" into a `Task<T>`.
- The `await` keyword (which you can think of as an operator), when applied to a `Task<T>`, will "unwrap" it, resulting in a value of type `T`.

Now, that's an extreme simplification; what's actually happening is more complicated. E.g., this simplification skips over how `await` works with the current `SynchronizationContext`: in the second example, the method will attempt to return to the original context after the `await` completes, so you will observe different behavior if that context is busy.

But for the most part, the two examples are almost equivalent. The second one is less efficient due to the `async` state machine and resuming on the context.

I have an [`async`/`await` intro](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) that you may find helpful; in that post I try to explain `async` in a way that is not *too* complex but also not actually *incorrect*. :)

Answer (score 7):

The answer to this question is too large to post here given your likely current level of understanding. What you should do is start by reading my MSDN article and then Mads' MSDN article; they are a good beginner introduction to the feature and Mads describes how it is implemented. You can find links here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/10/03/async-articles.aspx

Then if you are interested in the theory underlying the feature you should start by reading all my articles on continuation passing style:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/tags/continuation+passing+style/

Start from the bottom.  Once you understand the notion of *continuation*, you can then read my series of articles on how we designed the async feature:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/tags/async/

Comment: Jon skeet's series on async is also pretty nice: http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/tags/Eduasync/default.aspx

Comment: I'm going to read both yours and Jon's blog posts over the upcoming days. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Eric's obviously the expert here and his advice is sound, but to answer your specific question:

In the first version, the `async` keyword on the method is irrelevant and your `GetStringAsync` method returns the same `Task<string>` awaitable that's returned by `client.GetStringAsync`.

In the second version, the `async` keyword on the method is required because you're using `await` in the method and the `await` keyword creates and returns a separate `Task<string>` awaitable that completes once the awaitable from `client.GetStringAsync` completes.  When that occurs, the `await` then evaluates to the string that was asynchronously obtained by `client.GetStringAsync` which is returned as the result of your asynchronous method.

So to the caller of `GetStringAsync`, they're functionally the same, but the first version is cleaner.